# Ajax error while uploading image

Tags: ajax, media, wysiwyg

I had a content type with title, body(Long text and summary) and image upload field. TinyMCE editor is added to body field. But once i tried to upload an image i am getting this error:

> An error occurred while attempting to process /system/ajax: params is
>   undefined.

I changed body Text processing from *Filtered text* (user selects text format) to *Plain text* and tried to upload an image. That works fine. But I need the editor for body field. What is causing this error?

Comment: Check if any java-script error occurred while using TinyMCE.

Comment: How can i check it. I didn't found any error in console. Error just popup when i click on browse image button.

Comment: The issue comes when i use jQuery 1.7. If i use version 1.5 (from jQuery update module) it works.